# Swift 3 - matching user input with dictionary values

Tags: swift

The user of my app will be tested on their english. They will select different words from a list by placing a check mark next to the word. They will want to ONLY select the words that are nouns. If, for example, they choose 5 out of 10 correctly, how do I show them a score of 50%. I think that I need to filter dictionary values based on the user's input. The user's input being an array. What is the best way to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
     let myDictionary : [String : Any] =
        [  "Nouns":["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"],
"Verbs":["Eat","play","dance","walk","run","sing","read","write","go","come"]]
    var myUserSelectedArray:[String] = ["One","come","Three","go","Five","x","Six","x","x","Ten"];
    
    let myNounArray = myDictionary["Nouns"] as? [String];
    let myVerbArray = myDictionary["Verbs"] as? [String];
    let set1:Set<String> = Set(myUserSelectedArray);
    let set2:Set<String> = Set(myNounArray!);
    let set3:Set<String> = Set(myVerbArray!);
    let scroeInNoun = set1.intersection(set2).count;
    let scroeInVerb = set1.intersection(set3).count;
    print ("score in Verb \((scroeInVerb * 100)/set2.count) %")
    print ("score in noun \((scroeInNoun * 10)/set3.count ) %")
    let finalScore = (scroeInNoun + scroeInVerb) * 100 / ((myNounArray?.count)! + (myVerbArray?.count)!)
    print ("final score in noun \(finalScore) %")
```

Comment: yes using simple math equation (correct answer * 100)/ total asked questions